# How to smooth the movement of the camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is such a code for the camera -

```
cam.transform.Rotate (-cameraRotation);
```

Thus, I try to smooth the movement of the camera -

```
var orgRotation = this.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
cameraRotation = Vector3.Lerp (orgRotation, cameraRotation, 5);
cam.transform.Rotate (-cameraRotation);
```

cameraRotation is the x-axis (mouse).

But Lerp does not work, so I did not fix the time, why?

Answer (score 0):

Lerp is basically used to lerp between two values
You have done two things wrong.
First you are changing cameraRotaion value though it should be the final value which you have to go. Use a temp variable for instead.
Second you have to put the value between 0 to 1 in third parameter where you used 5 which will be considered as 1. It work on percentage 0 means starting value 1 means ending value.
So you have to use it on Update function or in a Coroutine where you have to check if final rotation reached and stop that.

Comment: That is to me all the processing of the rotation of the camera is done in Coroutine? Or call Coroutin from the rotation processing method?